# what does setContentView do?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm very new to android and am trying to learn as much as possible. I have noticed a layout xml file has this line

```
tools:context=".Main2Activity"
```

And the activity has this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
```

Obviously these are linking the two files together in some way but what exactly do they do?

If I switch to Main2Activity is the layout displayed automatically?

And if I change to the layout does it switch to the activity for me, or do I still need to change the activity manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one thing that must be clarified here.

It's true that `setContentView(R.layout.acivity_main2);` will link the layout file to your Activity. However, `tools:context=".Main2Activity"` **does not** link your Activity to your layout file in the way you're thinking it does.

First, you need to take note of the word `tools` in that line. `tools` is the name typically used for the `tools` namespace which provides a few xml attributes that only works during design-time. Take a look at this documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes

Note how it said that when you're building your app, everything related to `tools` will be stripped out. Therefore, `tools:context=".Main2Activity"` plays zero role in linking your Activity to the layout.

Instead, it's only meant to link it during design, by allowing you to **Preview** your layout in a container that mimics the Activity you set in `tools:context=`. So if you have a certain Theme for that Activity, the Preview will reflect the theme in the Preview Window.

On the other hand, `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);` does play a **major** role in linking your xml layout to your Activity.

That statement is telling the Activity to *inflate* that xml layout and fetch all of it's Views and more. Essentially, by using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);` you're telling the `Activity` that you **want** to use that layout file, so please create your layout using that file as the guidelines.

After you called `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);` your Activity will know which layout you want to use, therefore making it possible to find the Views you want to work with through methods like `findViewById()`. This wouldn't be possible if you never used `setContentView()`.

Therefore, to answer your last two questions:

1. Switching Main2Activity to another Activity in your layout xml file will do nothing besides show you how your layout will look if it was placed inside the other Activity. It won't change the outcome of your app at all. All for designing purposes.
2. Switching to another layout file in `setContentView()` will completely change the layout used in the Activity. Be careful of doing this, since if you have code used only for Views in the original layout, this WILL cause a crash if that code runs for the 2nd layout, because those Views don't exist anymore.

Bottomline is:

- `tools:context=".Main2Activity"` - This is unnecessary for connecting your Activity and layout.
- `setContentView(R.layout.acivity_main2);` - This is necessary for connecting your Activity and layout.